# Jpg Photo to point layer

Tags: arcgis-9.3, jpg, vectorization, geotag

How do I open a Geotag (.jpg) Photo in ArcGIS 9.3 (or photo to point)? In 10 and above versions it shows an ArcPhoto option in Data Management tools, but not in Arcgis 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download **[ArcPhoto for 9.x (Version 1.5.3) 27MB](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5785704e6cd24498887c4d996063529f)**.

Among other features it has some geoprocessing tools to support you with converting your geotagged photos to a point feature class.

Comment: I wasn't able to install ArcPhoto for 9.x (1.5.3) and contacted ESRI (Thomas Emge) about that.

He replied: "I just tried to install the tools on 9.3.1 and the install failed for me. It failed for me in a way where the appropriate information is not entered into the computer’s registry and as a result of that the tools are not available.
At this point I think you are out of luck getting the tool to install and to run. It might be time to remove the tool and download link for the 9.x version."

Anybody has an idea to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you have administrative privileges before installation. Editing the windows registery requires that. Why not upgrading to a more recent version of ArcGIS and ArcPhoto which are less buggy?!

Comment: I have admin rights, thats not the problem. An Upgrade to ArcGIS 10.x is no solution: 9.3.1 does everything we want and my boss is probably not willing to pay ESRI another pile of money just for this small feature. When I'm back to office on monday I'm going to give this a try: http://njgeo.org/2010/06/01/script-geotagged-photos-to-gis/